# Angular/Bootstrap data-target not evaluating expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have in my jade/pug file:

```
div(ng-repeat='writing in user.clean_profile.writing_samples track by $index')
    a(toggle target="collapse" data-target="{{\'#collapse\'+$index+1}}") Link {{$index+1}}
    iframe.collapse(id="collapse{{$index+1}}" toggleable ng-src='{{preview(writing.url)}}', frameborder='0' )
```

(equivalently)

```
<div ng-repeat="writing in user.clean_profile.writing_samples track by $index">
    <a toggle="toggle" target="collapse" data-target="{{'#collapse'+$index+1}}">Link {{$index+1}}</a>
    <iframe id="collapse{{$index+1}}" toggleable="toggleable" ng-src="{{preview(writing.url)}}" frameborder="0" class="collapse"></iframe>
</div>
```

However, the link is not evaluating correctly: the actual html data-target element evaluates to {{'#collapse'+$index+1}} instead of 0,1,2, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element has already been assigned a value to the attribute `something`, the binding to the `data-something` **after that** will not work and vice versa.

So you need change either the `target` attribute or the `data-target` to enable the binding. Or put the binding one before the not binding one.

The reason for this issue in in the way angular creates the attributes map of an element.

In the source code of angular *complie.js* around [line 2081](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2081):

```
        nName = directiveNormalize(name.toLowerCase());
        attrsMap[nName] = name;
        if (isNgAttr || !attrs.hasOwnProperty(nName)) {
            attrs[nName] = value;
            if (getBooleanAttrName(node, nName)) {
              attrs[nName] = true; // presence means true
            }
        }
```

Here `isNgAttr` is the value holding whether the current processing attribute is an attribute with `ng-` prefix.

The `directiveNormalize` function will eliminate the 'data-' prefix of attribute.

So now the `data-something` and `something` share the same name in the element's attribute map.

By the code above, the attribute's value in `attrs` will always keep the **FIRST ONE** of these two.

Comment: I am sorry but there was in fact mistakes in my previous answer. I have updated it. I misunderstood the `isNgAttr` 's meaning. The `attrs` will allways keep the first one no matter if is is need to be interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

In **Angular2** you can do it with `[attr]`

```
<a toggle="toggle" target="collapse" 
    [attr.data-target]="'#collapse'+$index+1">
    Link {{$index+1}}
</a>
<iframe id="collapse{{$index+1}}" toggleable="toggleable" 
    [src]="preview(writing.url)" frameborder="0" 
    class="collapse">
</iframe>
```

Maybe someone helps this out.

Comment: [attr.data-target]="'#collapse'+$index+1" allowed me to use an index in a bootstrap collapse.  Thank you!